# Error while unit test - TypeError: Cannot read property 'cityWeather' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing

In Component.ts,

```
this.dataService.currentCity.subscribe(info => {
  this.cities = info;
});

this.dataService.currentSelectedCity.subscribe(index => {
  this.selectedCityIndex = index;
});

this.selectedCityInfo = this.cities[this.selectedCityIndex];
this.selectedCityWeatherList = this.selectedCityInfo.cityWeather.list;
```

I am trying to test this piece of code in `ngOnInit()`. But I am unsure how to test this code. Here, my other component is sending me an array of objects and also the index of the selected item using Behavior subject to which I am subscribing in this component's `ngOnInit(). And trying to access cityWeather property in the selected object.

In Spec.ts I am tried something like this which I am sure is not a correct way of testing this.

```
it("should handle ngOnInit", async(() => {
        let response;
        const dataService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(DataService);  
        spyOn(dataService, 'currentCity').and.returnValue(of(response));
        component.ngOnInit();
        expect(component.cities).toEqual(response);
    }));
```

When I run the application, I am getting the output but when I test ngoninit function then I am not getting the response from subscribe. I am getting the below error. `Failed: Cannot read property 'cityWeather' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'cityWeather' of undefined`

In data.service.ts

```
private citySubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
currentCity = this.citySubject.asObservable();
private selectedCity = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
currentSelectedCity= this.selectedCitySubject.asObservable();

sendCityWeatherInfo(info,index) {
  this.citySubject.next(info);
  this.selectedCitySubject.next(index);
}
```

I am calling this in a component like this (passing an array of objects and index)

```
this.dataService.sendCityWeatherInfo(this.cities, index);
```

Comment: Can you add full component code?

And what about spyOn spyOn(dataService, 'currentSelectedCity') ? Have you returned an observable value to that too?

Part of the problem could be that this.selectedCityIndex is still undefined, since the observable hasn't returned.

Comment: @HarijsDeksnis I have updated my code. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't in your test, it's in this line:

```
this.selectedCityInfo = this.cities[this.selectedCityIndex];
```

`this.cities` and `this.selectedCityIndex` haven't been defined yet - you subscribed to `dataService` which will update them, but the service didn't run. Also, when the service does run, `this.selectedCityInfo` won't be updated.

Instead, update these values whenever you receive new data. A simple solution is:

```
  this.dataService.currentCity.subscribe(info => {
    this.cities = info;
    this.updateSelectedCity();
  });

  this.dataService.currentSelectedCity.subscribe(index => {
    this.selectedCityIndex = index;
    this.updateSelectedCity();
  });
}

...

updateSelectedCity() {
  this.selectedCityInfo = this.cities[this.selectedCityIndex];
  this.selectedCityWeatherList = this.selectedCityInfo.cityWeather.list;
}
```

For testing, `this.selectedCityInfo` and `this.selectedCityWeatherList` aren't being tested. I'm not familiar with the testing library but you probably want something like `expect(component.selectedCityInfo).toEqual(...)`, ditto with `this.selectedCityWeatherList`.

Comment: still I am getting the same error. When I changed my code according to your suggestion I am getting the same error in the browser as well. Previously I was getting it only when I test it(ng test).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with observable streams which are asynchronous in nature,
`this.cities` and `this.selectedCityIndex` can get updated in unknown order or at unknown time.

Therefore, the following synchronous code falls pray to chance of dealing with undefined values.

```
this.selectedCityInfo = this.cities[this.selectedCityIndex];
this.selectedCityWeatherList = this.selectedCityInfo.cityWeather.list;
```

For example, when you try to assign `this.selectedCityInfo`, `this.cities` or `this.selectedCityIndex` could be undefined and the assignment would fail.
What is more, in your service you initialise both of your behaviour subjects with empty strings.. which is of different data type.

This sort of design is inviting various problems and unexpected behaviours.
I would suggest to steer clear of architecting your dataflow in this way.

Instead, I'd suggest to either combine both observables in one subscription by using [combineLatest](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest) function, or refactoring bits the following way:

Since in your service updateSelectedCity method you emit from both observables at the same time, perhaps (if it fits your application) it would be easier to emit both values in a single observable? Then we would know that both values definitely arrive and we can do `this.selectedCityInfo` and `this.selectedCityWeatherList` assignments in subscribe callback function.

In service:

```
/* you can keep private property and recast it to Observable,
but you can also subscribe to Subjects and BehaviorSubjects directly
since they extend Observable class.
So that's what I'm doing here */

cityWeatherInfo$ =  = new BehaviorSubject<any>({ info: null, index: null });

sendCityWeatherInfo(info,index) {
  this.cityWeatherInfo$.next({ info, index });

}
```

In component:

```
this.dataService.cityWeatherInfo$
  .subscribe(({ info, index }) => {
    if (info !== null && index !== null) {
      this.cities = info;
      this.selectedCityIndex = index;
      this.selectedCityInfo = this.cities[this.selectedCityIndex];
      this.selectedCityWeatherList = this.selectedCityInfo.cityWeather.list;
    }    
  });
```

P.S. I don't know all your app's requirements, but perhaps you can use simple `Subject` instead of `BehaviorSubject` in your service. That way it wouldn't emit initial null values and `if (info !== null && index !== null)` check would not be necessary.